# Can you add an onclick function to a class of divs and then use event.target to extract the innerHTML from the specific div that was clicked on?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm practicing building a tip calculator using vanilla JS (don't know JQuery). Here is the link: https://codepen.io/decopage/pen/qwVdmm

What I want is for the person to be able to click one of the 15, 20, 25% divs to choose their tip percentage and then click calculate to get the answer.

So I assigned an onclick attribute to the percentage divs, targeting them with their ID. Then I set the onclick function to calculate the percent based on which div was clicked using event.target.innerHTML and then parseInt to parse the innerHTML into an integer.

I then plan to addEventListener to the calculate button and assign the onclick function's answer to a variable inside addEventListener and get the final answer.

My problem is I think I am using event.target incorrectly (I am still a bit confused on how to use it).

Here is setting the onclick attribute and the function calculating percentage

```
const percentage = document.querySelectAll("#amounts");
percentage.setAttribute("onclick");
percentage.onclick = function calculatepercent(event) {
 const num = event.target.innerHTML;
 const numper = parseInt(num);
 const billinp = bill.value;
 const peopinp = people.value;
 let result = (billinp/peopinp) * numper;
 console.log result; 
}
```

So when I click the div nothing outputs to the console which is where I'm stuck right now. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: typo to start: "querySelectorAll"

Comment: Then to boot you are adding an onClick to a list.

Comment: i fixed the typo but am confused about what you said about the list? The divs aren't part of a list.

Comment: querySelectorAll returns a list of nodes. You could try querySelector, or iterate through the nodes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to use the target's content as the percentage instead of just passing a value to your click handler?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to add a click handler to a list of nodes, iterate over the list and add the handler to the individual nodes like @JuanIsFree suggested.

```js
function getTip(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let tip = parseInt(e.target.innerHTML.replace('%', ''));
  console.log("TIP", tip);
}

let tips = document.querySelectorAll('#amount');

for (let i = 0; i < tips.length; i++) {
    tips[i].addEventListener('click', getTip);
}
```

```html
<div id="amount" style="margin-bottom: 10px; cursor: pointer;">0%</div>
<div id="amount" style="margin-bottom: 10px; cursor: pointer;">15%</div>
<div id="amount" style="margin-bottom: 10px; cursor: pointer;">20%</div>
```

There are some issues though that I would point out. One is that ids are supposed to be unique among HTML elements. You shouldn't have multiple divs with same id. Using a class or data-attr would be more appropriate. Also, extracting the value from the inner html seems excessively complicated.